# Wait combineLatest until #selector is called

Tags: swift, rx-swift

**TL;DR;**

I need to find out a way to setup `combineLatest` that processes events only after particular `self.myMethod()` is called **without subscribing in that method**.

**Description**

My component `A` has a `subscribe()` routin in `init()`, where all Rx subscriptions are set up.

```
import RxSwift

final class A {

    let bag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        //...
        subscribe()
    }

    //...

    private func subscribe() {
        // Setup all Rx subscriptions here
    }
```

There are two other dependencies `B` and `C`, each having their statuses that `A` needs to `combineLatest` and yield some UI Event upon that combination.

```
Observable.combineLatest(b.status,
                         c.status)
        .filter { $0.0 == .connecting && $0.1 == .notReachable }
        .map { _ -> Error in
            return AError.noInternet
        }
        .debounce(RxTimeInterval.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] error in
            self?.didFail(with: error)
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

`A` is not a UI component and basically handles business logic, thus it should wait until UI "says" it is ready to handle that business logic. E.g., after `myMethod()` is called on `A` by UI layer.

**Problem**

I do want to have the `Observable.combineLatest` in `subscribe()` being setup in a way that waits until `myMethod()` is called and then immediately receives latest events from `B`'s `status` and `C`'s `status`.

Currently I do it this way in `A`:

```
public func myMethod()
    // ... 
    Observable.combineLatest(...
}
```

, which breaks the clean code I am striving to.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is make the publisher connectable, and call `.connect()` when you need to:

```
let publisher: Publishers.MakeConnectable<AnyPublisher<YourOutput, YourError>>

func subscribe() {
   publisher = Observable.combineLatest(b.status, c.status)
                         .filter { ... }
                         .map { ... }
                         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                         .makeConnectable()

   publisher.subscribe(...)
}
```

Then, in `myMethod()` you can do:

```
func myMethod() {
   publisher.connect()
}
```

Comment: I like this solution! It's not often you see a valid reason to use connectable. In RxSwift, the operator is called `publish()` rather than `makeConnectable()`

Comment: Thank you. I am using **RxSwift**. After putting this suggestion together with the framework, I wonder about `.disposed(by: bag)` call required on both sides, upon '.subscribe(...)' and `.connect()`, unless the result is unused. Is it OK? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you know what... I didn't notice at all that you were asking about RxSwift. For some reason in my mind I thought it was about Combine. Haha

Comment: @NewDev I want to make your answer as an Accepted one. Could you please edit with RxSwift syntax for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with RxSwift, so can't really update my answer without more research. @YevhenDubinin

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add a PublishSubject to your `A` class.

```
final class A { 
    let myMethodCalled = PublishSubject<Void>()

    init() { 
        myMethodCalled 
            .withLatestFrom(Observable.combineLatest(a.status, b.status))
            // etc...
    }

    func myMethod() {
        myMethodCalled.onNext(())
    }
}
```

The above might be a problem if, for example `myMethod()` is called before a.status and b.status emit any values though.

The *best* solution is to pass in an Observable that triggers the whole thing instead of calling `myMethod()`. Embrace the Rx paradigm and get rid of the passive (as opposed to reactive) `myMethod()`.